# Filtering records in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Say I have a list of records and I want to filter them based on the select box selection the user makes. I have the details in the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

so if the user selects 1-10 only those numbers in 1 to 10 should show. 
How do we add an event handler to filter all the records?

```
var numbers =   [   
    {"number":1},    {"number":2},    {"number":3},    {"number":4},    {"number":5},    {"number":6},    {"number":7},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":18},    {"number":11},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":21},    {"number":41},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},     {"number":14},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":81},    {"number":12},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":1},    {"number":111}
];
var DisplayNumbers = React.createClass({    
render: function(){

return (
<div>
    {this.props.allnumbers}
  </div>
);
}
       });
 var FilterBox = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return { selected: "1-10" }
      },      

            render: function() {
        return (
          React.createElement("select", { value: this.state.selected },
             React.createElement("option", { value: 1 }, "1-10"),
             React.createElement("option", { value: 2 }, "11-20"),
             React.createElement("option", { value: 3 }, "21-30"), 
          React.createElement("option", { value: 4 }, "31-40")
          )
        )
      }
    });


var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {              
        return (
        <div>
          <FilterBox />
                      <h1>Requests</h1>
                <DisplayNumbers allnumbers={this.props.data} />
          </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<App data={numbers}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: The JS fiddle only contains a hello world example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Scarysize suggested you must provide `onChange` event handlers to your form elements. Also here in `DisplayNumbers` component you are trying to render an array of js objects, but react won't render it. It must be an array of legal react components in order to be rendered that way.

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sehrob/r4c2ycmc/ - I have made some changes to your code to make it workable. You can use it if you want.

P.S. [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) also can be very useful for you to implement your app.

Answer (score 0):

Just attach a `onChange` handler to your `select` element. The handler should update your components state, which will result in a re-render. In the render function you can then figure out which elements to display, based you the new state.

Also take a look at the Array functions `map` and `filter` they might help you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map